# Relational algebra with multiple joins

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I'm trying to write the following question as relational algebra:

Pnr and pname for all products which have a substitute product with a lower price.

The relations I have are these:

```
Product(Pnr, Pname, Price) //Product info
Substprod(Pnr, Subst-Pnr) //Product which can replace other products
```

If I do it in SQL it would look something like this:

```
SELECT p.pnr, p.pname
FROM Product p1, Substprod s, Product p2
WHERE p1.pnr = s.pnr
AND s.subst_pnr = p2.pnr
AND p1.price > p2.price
```

But I can't see how I can get the same result in relational algebra. I'm guessing that I need to do a 3-way-join here too, but having trouble with the condition that one price on a particular product should be lower than its substitute.

Comment: Eequi-joins is the the commonest type joins but the condition for a join does not have to be equality. It can be anything and the general term is "theta-join" ("θ-join"). See [Wikipedia page on joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like that? A bit rusty on the exact syntax, but the general idea is there.

```
T1 <- ρ pris = substpris (Product ⨝ Substprod)
T2 <- σ price > substprice (T1 ⨝ Product)
T3 <- π pnr,name (T2)
```